# What does "Mouse X" and "Mouse Y" return in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mouse, user-input

I wrote the following update:

```
void Update () {

        if( Input.GetMouseButton(0) )
        {

            if( !dragging )
            {
                dragging = true;

                xDragStart = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
                yDragStart = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");
            }


            xDrag = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
            yDrag = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

            DragValuesText.text = "x = " + xDrag + ", y = " + yDrag;
        }
        else
        {
            if( dragging )
            {
                dragging = false;
            }
        }


    }
```

and made a `Text` UI to display `DragValuesText`. After this I found, that returned values are small while I am dragging and turn to zero if I stop the mouse. Looks like they return delta. But how can I be sure?

[In documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) I don't see it is definitely delta. It says it CAN be delta, but how to know or change this fact -- it is not said.

Answer (score 3):

Go into Edit -> Project Settings -> Input and check the settings for the Mouse X / Mouse Y axes.

The `Type` should be "Mouse movement" by default, which means its "mouse delta"

> Use Key / Mouse Button for any kind of buttons, Mouse Movement for
>   mouse delta and scrollwheels, Joystick Axis for analog joystick axes
>   and Window Movement for when the user shakes the window.

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html

Comment: So it is impossible to configure absolute values? What units these deltas are in?

Comment: Im not sure what unit actually.. If you want to know the absolute changes in pixels i guess you could store Input.mousePosition on mousedown and check difference every frame