# Difference between "Mouse X" and "Horizontal" in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm a beginner at Unity.

I'm making a camera that applies to the main character. I used this code:

```
void Update()
{
    var x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    var y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    if (x != MouseX || y != MouseY)
    {
        rotationX += x * sensX * Time.deltaTime;
        rotationY += y * sensY * Time.deltaTime;
        rotationY = Mathf.Clamp(rotationY, minY, maxY);
        MouseX = x;
        MouseY = y;
        Camera.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(-rotationY, rotationX, 0);
    }

}
```

I saw this site but I don't know the difference "Mouse X" and "Horizontal"

URL: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50889727/what-does-mouse-x-and-mouse-y-return-in-unity

Comment: "Mouse X" and "Horizontal" are just names of axes as defined in the [Input Manager](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/input-manager). By default, "Horizontal" is mapped to the left joystick of most controllers and to the A and D keys. By default, "Mouse X" is mapped to horizontal mouse movement.

Answer (score 1):

'Horizontal' is mapped to the keyboard arrow keys or a joystick and its value ranges from -1 to 1.
'Mouse X' is mapped to the mouse movement which gives the difference between your mouse initial and final position along x axis.

So basically to take a mouse input use 'Mouse X' and for keyboard's arrow keys use 'Horizontal'